# Is there a way to record the time before and after the routing operation in NettyRoutingFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm building a gateway for my websites, and using spring-cloud-gateway. I want to record some timestamps in a request, including the time when request comes in ***(1)*** , the time when sending the response ***(2)*** , and the time before and after the route operation ***(3)*** .
I can get ***(1)*** and ***(2)*** by the following code:

```java
@Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {


        exchange.getAttributes().put(START_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());

        Mono<Void> mono = chain.filter(exchange);

        return mono.then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

            GatewayLog gatewayLog = new GatewayLog();

            /** some codes of building the gatewayLog **/

            String jsonMsg = JSON.toJSONString(gatewayLog);

            mono.log(jsonMsg);
            logger.info(jsonMsg);
        }));
    }
```

But the route operation is executed by the filter 'NettyRoutingFilter', and I don't know how to get the timestamp of ***(3)*** by using WebFlux. 
Can I add a Method into mono which could execute when NettyRoutingFilter.filter() works?
Or do you have other solutions?